# HeapSort Code snipplet giving Index Out of bound exception

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception, heapsort

I am trying the following code for heap sort which is giving `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception:

```java
package com.Sorting;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class HeapSort {

    private static int arr[];
    private static int l,r,max,hsize;
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int []numbers={55,2,93,1,23,10,66,12,7,54,3};
          System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
          HeapSort(numbers);
          System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
    }

    private static void HeapSort(int myarr[]) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        arr = myarr;
         hsize = arr.length - 1;
        BuildHeap(arr);
        for(int i = hsize;i>0;i--)
        {
            swap(0,i);
            hsize--;
            SatisfyHeap(arr,0);
        }       
        }

    private static void BuildHeap(int[] arr) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(int i = hsize/2; i>=0;i--)
        {
            SatisfyHeap(arr, i);

        }
    }

    private static void SatisfyHeap(int[] arr, int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         l = 2*i;
         r = 2*i+1;
        if(l<=hsize && arr[l]>arr[i])
    //  if(arr[l]>arr[i] && l<=hsize  )
        {
            max = l;
        }
        else
            max = i;
        if(r<=hsize && arr[r]>arr[max])
        {
            max = r;
        }

        if(max!=i)
        {
            swap(i,max);
            SatisfyHeap(arr, max);
        }

    }

    private static void swap(int i, int max) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[max];
        arr[max] = temp;    
    }
}
```

The above code does not give any error if I just swap the expressions used on the left hand side and right hand side in the `if` statement of `SatisfyHeap` method. i.e. you can try commenting the third line of the `SatisfyHeap` method and uncomment the fourth line. Please help to understand this magic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**

The magic is called ["short-circuit evaluation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and it was designed speciifcally for the cases like this.

**Longer answer**

In Java and many other languages logicallly code

```java
if (condition1 && condition2) { 
    do something 
}
```

is equivalent to

```java
if (condition1) {
    if (condition2) { 
        do something 
    }
}
```

By "equivalent" here I mean that if `condition2` is something to be computed it will not be computed if `condition1` happens to be `false`. Also this is correct from the boolean logic point of view. This trick is useful in two respects. First, it improves performance by skipping evaluation `calculation2`. Secondly, it is useful in cases such as yours were `condition1` is a "guard condition" for `condition2`.

Another example is function `isEmptyString` that is implemented by many Java-developers in a following way

```java
public static boolean isEmptyString(String s) {
    return (string == null) || (string.length() == 0);
}
```

Without short-circuting logic, this expression would raise a `NullPointerException` if `s` happens to be null.

**Your specific case** (Why `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` at all?)

Another point of your question might be "How it happens that there is `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` at all?". To answer this question consider the case when the very first element is actually the largest in the heap and we should move it down to the last layer of the tree. This movement down is implemented by your `SatisfyHeap`. So now assume that we did last swap that moved the biggest element to the bottom. Now as `max` was changed we'll do one more recursive call and in that call `i > arr.length / 2` so `l = 2*i > arr.length` and thus the exception happens.

Side-note, I'd say that unless you pre-allocate `arr` to be bigger than actual heap size storing `hsize` independently from `arr.length` is a bad idea that makes code harder to understand.

Comment: @Tapan, if you think that some of the answers are useful, you can vote them up. And if there is an answer that actually fits your question well, you can mark it as an "accepted" answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following gives you an error

`if(arr[l]>arr[i] && l<=hsize  )`

because `l` is greater than the size of the array and you are trying to get the array element by passing `l` which is out of array's bounds.

Following works for you

`if(l<=hsize && arr[l]>arr[i])`

because in the `if` condition, the first thing that is evaluated is the expression `l<=hsize`. Since `l` is greater than `hsize`, the expression evaluates to false. Since the two clauses of your `if` predicate are joined with an `&&` operator, as per the short circuiting rules, the expression in the second clause is not even evaluated saving you from accessing the array with an out of bound index. Therefore you don't get any error.